# PHP get mimetype not working docs

Tags: php, upload

I want to only upload images, the docs says use finfo_open.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

I do this but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ticket\index.php on line 83 Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  2.2551  158752  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $ext = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['name']); << LINE 84
       if(substr($ext, 0, 5) != 'image') {
          $errors[] = 'Kon dit bestand type niet uploaden.';
       }
}
```

Why does this not work?

UPDATE:

By settings extension=php_fileinfo.dll active I get this now:

> Warning: finfo_file(download.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ticket\index.php on line 84 Call Stack
>
> ## Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  2.2531  158448  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0 2    3.2572  180560  finfo_file ( )  ..\index.php:84

Comment: finfo_open need PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: I have: PHP Version 5.4.7

Comment: check if php.ini fileinfo.so is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.3.0 and later have Fileinfo built in, but on Windows you must enable it manually in your php.ini

Have a look at your php.ini file and check that the fileinfo.so or php_fileinfo.dll is activated (depending on your platform and version).

There should be a line similar to

```
extension = fileinfo.so
```

on windows

```
extension = fileinfo.dll
```

in your php.ini file

**AFTER UPDATE**

use [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)['file']['tmp_name'] for path ([finfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) need path!)

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $ext = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    if(substr($ext, 0, 5) != 'image') {
       $errors[] = 'Kon dit bestand type niet uploaden.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked, but now I get this: Warning: finfo_file(download.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ticket\index.php on line 84
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 2.2531 158448 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 3.2572 180560 finfo_file ( ) ..\index.php:84